# Update to 20.04: Missing icons and icon alignments

Tags: gnome, icons

I've just updated my system to Ubuntu 20.04. I'm facing issues with missing icons and alignment of icons in the top bar. I've attached screenshots below.

Misaligned Icons:
[image: Misaligned Icons]

Missing Icons:
[image: Missing Icons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try resetting the icons to the standard icon theme (eg. Yaru).

Had the same issue. I was using a non-standard icon theme called "paper" that is not available for focal.

Changing to a preinstalled icon theme using "Tweak Tools" solved both problems for me.
["appearance" tab in Tweak Tools where one can change the icon theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO9bJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed mine too. I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04. What I did was that I installed Tweek Tools from Ubuntu Software. With it, I made some adjustment.

Then, I started recovery mode from GRUB (Boot) with my Wi-Fi on. Then, I upgraded from there. This fixes the issue.