# Icons in Gnome top bar misplaced and overlapping with applications

Tags: gnome, icons, wayland, scaling, hdpi

this week I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and connected it to my external 27" screen (EIZO 27" with 3840x2160px).

In order to enable video acceleration in Firefox via VA-API I switched to Wayland. Since all desktop elements are very small on the HiDPI external screen I enabled the "experimental-features" to allow for fractional scaling of 125% ...

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"`

**So far it looked good except the top bar overlapping the dash and the top right icons moving out of the top bar. Apart from being an optical glitch it also impacts usability because the icons overlap application windows.**

Screenshot of top bar with misplaced icons
[image: Screenshot of top bar with misplaced icons]

I blamed it to the "experimental-features" and the 125% setting but when I turn off the "experimental features" and revert to 100% the setting persists. Even if I switch back to the "old" X-Server and disable Wayland.

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue or is it not a configuration issue but a bug?

Thanks a lot!

Daniel

Comment: Probably I should not ask but you did not mention in your post: did this persist after logging out/rebooting?

Comment: Check here for a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231375/update-to-20-04-missing-icons-and-icon-alignments Let us know if that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! You were exactly right: The issue was that I activated the paper icon theme.
I tried switching to a different icon theme myself before when trying to locate the error but when I changed the icon set in Gnome tweak tools nothing changed so I thought this was not the issue. Apparently I need to change the icon set and hoover with the cursor over the icons to make the change effective.